# php have code skip button click to next step and go straight to the next step automatically

Tags: php

I am editing a template that currently has two steps. I want to make it automatically go to step two upon loading, or skip step 1 altogether. I have tried using the `header`function but that didnt seem to get me what I needed.

At the bottom of the page on step 1 there is a "create new product button" that is the link I am trying to skip to without having to click the button.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 add-product-outer-wrapper">
    <div class="select-product-cat-wrapper">
        <?php $is_new_listing = isset($_REQUEST['new_listing']) ? true : false;
        $is_cats_hier = isset($_REQUEST['cats_hier']) ? true : false;
        if( ( $is_new_listing && $is_cats_hier ) || !get_wcmp_vendor_settings('is_singleproductmultiseller', 'general') == 'Enable' ) {
        ?>
        <!-- New product list categories hierarchically -->
       <div class="select-cat-step-wrapper">
            <div class="cat-step1" >
                <div class="panel panel-default pannel-outer-heading mt-0">
                    <div class="panel-heading d-flex">
                        <h1><span class="primary-color"><span><?php _e( 'Step 1 of', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor' );?></span> <?php _e( '2:', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor' );?></span> <?php _e('Select a product category', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'); ?></h1>
                        <h3><?php _e('Once a category is assigned to a product, it cannot be altered.', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'); ?></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body panel-content-padding form-horizontal breadcrumb-panel">
                       
                        <?php echo $url; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default pannel-outer-heading wcmp-categories-level-panel has-scroller"> 
                        <div class="cat-column-scroller cat-left-scroller"><i class="wcmp-font ico-left-arrow-icon"></i></div>
                    <div class="form-horizontal cat-list-holder">
                        <div class="wcmp-product-categories-wrap cat-column-wrapper">
                            <div class="wcmp-product-cat-level 1-level-cat cat-column" data-level="1"  data-mcs-theme="dark">
                                <ul class="wcmp-product-categories 1-level" data-cat-level="1">
                                    <?php echo wcmp_list_categories( apply_filters( 'wcmp_vendor_product_classify_1_level_categories', array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 
                                    'hide_empty' => false, 
                                    'html_list' => true,
                                    'cat_link'  => 'javascript:void(0)',
                                    ) ) ); ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="cat-column-scroller cat-right-scroller"><i class="wcmp-font ico-right-arrow-icon"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php }else{ ?>
        <!-- List a product by name or gtin -->
       <div class="cat-intro">
            <div class="panel panel-default pannel-outer-heading mt-0"> 
                <div class="panel-body panel-content-padding form-horizontal text-center">
                    <img src="<?php echo $WCMp->plugin_url.'assets/images/add-product-graphic.png'; ?>" alt="">
                    <h1 class="heading-underline"><?php _e('List a New Product', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'); ?></h1>
                    <div class="serach-product-cat-wrapper">
                        <h2><?php// _e('Search from our existing Product Catalog', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'); ?></h2>

                        <?php 

                         if (get_option('permalink_structure')) {
                            $category_url = '?new_listing=1&cats_hier=1';
                        } else {
                            $category_url = wcmp_get_vendor_dashboard_endpoint_url( get_wcmp_vendor_settings( 'wcmp_add_product_endpoint', 'vendor', 'general', 'add-product' ) ) . '&new_listing=1&cats_hier=1';
                        }

                        $url = ( get_wcmp_vendor_settings('is_disable_marketplace_plisting', 'general') == 'Enable' ) ? esc_url(wcmp_get_vendor_dashboard_endpoint_url(get_wcmp_vendor_settings('wcmp_edit_product_endpoint', 'vendor', 'general', 'edit-product'))) : $category_url; ?>
                        <p><?php //_e('Not in the catalog?', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'); ?> <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="cat-step-btn"><?php _e('Create a new product', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'); ?> <i class="wcmp-font ico-right-arrow-icon"></i></a></p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- End List a product by name or gtin -->
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From within a template, it is usually a little late to use header - likely, output will have created at this point already. This should probably be handled, before this template even renders. But for anything more specific, your question currently contains way too little detail.

Comment: im not sure what more detail to add?